# returning a declared Boolean?

Tags: java, syntax, boolean

Doing some Codingbat exercises, how does `return talking;` work?
The code is a working solution to the following exercise:

> We have a loud talking parrot. The "hour" parameter is the current hour time in the range 0..23. We are in trouble if the parrot is talking and the hour is before 7 or after 20. Return true if we are in trouble.
>   examples:
>
> ```
> parrotTrouble(true, 6) → true
> parrotTrouble(true, 7) → false
> parrotTrouble(false, 6) → false
> ```

Solution:

```
public boolean parrotTrouble(boolean talking, int hour) 
{
  if (hour < 7 || hour > 20) {
    return talking;
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

How and why does `return talking;` work? Is this a Java shortcut?

Comment: That's how variables work. What's confusing you about it?

Comment: I'm confused on the meaning, I'm reading it as: "If the hour is less and 7 or greater than 20, return (word that holds a value of true or false).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return type of the `parrotTrouble` method is `boolean`, which means that it can return any boolean *literal* (`true` or `false`) or *variable*, even one that's passed in as a parameter (`talking`).

The logic is equivalent to this (much more verbose) version which uses only boolean literals as return values:

```
public boolean parrotTrouble(boolean talking, int hour) {
    if (hour < 7 || hour > 20) {
        if (talking) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else
        return false;
}
```

As you can see, the check for `if (talking)` is redundant, because you may as well return the variable itself.

Answer (score 0):

If it's daytime, return `false` because there's no trouble.

If it's nighttime, return the value of `talking`.
If `talking` is `true`, that returns `true`, indicating there's trouble.
If `talking` is `false`, that returns `false`, indicating there's no trouble.

A better(?) simpler implementation would be:

```
public static boolean parrotTrouble(boolean talking, int hour) {
    return (talking && (hour < 7 || hour > 20));
}
```

**Thought:** I could argue that "after 20" means `hour >= 20`, because at 20:01, it's "after 20". Only at the exact second of 8 PM is `=` not correct, and you'd need minute and second to know that.

Answer (score 0):

According to your problem definition, we can only be in trouble if the time is in the timeframe 20:00 - 06:59. If we find that this is the case, the solution as to whether we are in trouble equals whether or not the parrot is talking, i.e. if we have `talking == true` then we also have `trouble == true` and as such we can simply return the value of `talking` directly.

Answer (score 0):

`talking` isn't a "word", it's a `boolean` value.  It can either be `true`, or `false`.  Your method returns a `boolean`, and thus can return either `true` or `false`.  The `return talking;` line simply means "return the value that was passed in".  In other words, this method returns `true` if passed `true` and `false` if passed `false` outside the hours 7AM-8PM.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't une the talking param to decide the return, I propose this code:

```
public static boolean parrotTrouble(boolean talking, int hour) 
{
    if (((hour < 7 || hour > 20) && talking) || (hour >= 7 && hour <= 20 && !talking))
        return true;
    else 
        return false;
}
```